# node.js get where a rejected promise was constructed

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following code extracted from one of the npm packages I recently used. The problem is, I cannot get node to report correctly where the rejected promise is constructed or rejected.

```
const someHiddenEvil = function(error) {
  return Promise.reject(error);
};

const doSomethingBad = function() {
  return Promise.reject(new Error('Bad Things Happened!'));
};

const doSomethingGood = function() {
  return Promise.resolve();
};

const onError = (err) => {
  console.log('caught', err)
};

(function f() {
  let err;
  return doSomethingGood().then(()=>doSomethingBad()).catch((error) => {
    err = error;
    someHiddenEvil(error);
  }).then(()=>onError(err), ()=>onError(err))
})();
```

I tried `.catch` (of course it won't catch),  `process.on('unhandledRejection')` and `node --trace-warnings`. However, all of these just give me the same stacktrace:

```
Error: Bad Things Happened!
at doSomethingBad (/test.js:5:25)
at doSomethingGood.then (/test.js:18:37)
```

In fact the rejected promise is constructed within function `someHiddenEvil` and should be caught on an anonymous function of a `catch` callback. The information above indicates no clue about where the problem actually is. So is there a way in JavaScript to get the information?

**In short, when a library code is rather complicated, hard to read and not very well-formed, how to quickly address the problem in their lib that cause unhandled promise rejection?**

Comment: You call `someHiddenEvil` but you don't return its result to further chain.
What if you try `return someHiddenEvil()` instead.

Comment: @ArtemArkhipov thanks for your advice... but it is extracted from a rather complicated node module... only `onError` is exposed to me as a user. debugging an unfamiliar library is not very much friendly...

Comment: @SunriseFox still, you are initiating some function that you expect to return a promise. It's not clear why, regardless of how complicated it is, you can't return that promise. If you can't, that means there is a promise somewhere you are ignoring, and that's the root problem.

Comment: Actually the `onunhandledrejection` listener *should* get you the error from `someHiddenEvil`, *in addition* to the `onError` reporting of the bad things.

Comment: @SunriseFox Can you link the particular library code that you need help with? It may as well be a bug in the library, not doing their error reporting correctly.

Comment: @Bergi see [emailjs-imap-client](https://github.com/emailjs/emailjs-imap-client/issues/194) ...  I spent a lot of time to trace the problem, as the reported bad thing is in fact not what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Your way of handling errors is really weird. It should be

```
doSomethingGood().then(doSomethingBad).catch(error => {
    onError(error);
    return someHiddenEvil(error);
//  ^^^^^^
}).catch(onError);
```

You will need to return the promise created in `someHiddenEvil` back to the chain so that it can get caught.

Comment: thanks... I know how to solve this problem. In fact, I mean, how to locate `someHiddenEvil` in a complex lib as it may hide very deep and all the errors reported by node are irrelevant. The code above is what I just simplified from a complex lib to make it more clear.